# Why have job postings disappeared from my feed?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, ios-app

I used to see daily job postings in my feed, but they seem to have vanished. I am not actively looking for jobs, but I like to see them anyway. I have not changed my settings relating to job status, and the area I work in usually has hundreds of listings. Has something changed?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by feed?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said - in the mobile app, the feed is the default view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We removed these from mobile feeds a few months back. They had very low click-through rates and there are better mechanisms for subscribing to jobs that may interest you; notably by creating a job alert using https://stackoverflow.com/jobs.